# Wy arange and linspace does not produce equal objects?

Tags: python, arrays

Wy arange and linspace does not produce the same result on the code below?

```
a = np.arange(12,17,.2, dtype=float)
b = np.linspace(12.,16.8,25, dtype=float)
print(list(a)==list(b))
```

The number of elements and the elements theyself is the same, apparently. But:

```
a==b
```

results not equal.

I expect the output of '''True''', but the actual output is '''False'''.

See !https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWA23.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for _a, _b in zip(a, b):
    print (_a, _b)
```

Based on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html,
You can see why it is not same from result as following:

```
12.0 12.0
12.2 12.2
12.399999999999999 12.4
12.599999999999998 12.6
12.799999999999997 12.8
12.999999999999996 13.0
13.199999999999996 13.2
13.399999999999995 13.4
13.599999999999994 13.6
13.799999999999994 13.8
13.999999999999993 14.0
14.199999999999992 14.200000000000001
14.399999999999991 14.4
14.59999999999999 14.600000000000001
14.79999999999999 14.8
14.99999999999999 15.0
15.199999999999989 15.200000000000001
15.399999999999988 15.4
15.599999999999987 15.600000000000001
15.799999999999986 15.8
15.999999999999986 16.0
16.199999999999985 16.200000000000003
16.399999999999984 16.400000000000002
16.599999999999984 16.6
16.799999999999983 16.8
```

In temporary, We can use `np.round` for just this problem.

```
a = np.arange(12,17,.2, dtype=np.float)
a = np.round(a, 1)
b = np.linspace(12.,16.8,25, dtype=np.float)
b = np.round(a, 1)

print (np.array_equal(a,b))
```

It returns `True`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll study the link you shared. But what does mean "dtype=bool" after the list of array elements?

Comment: @André data type object (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) of bool what returns a Boolean value in True or False.